# Does using Discern Location or Wish to determine something's location also provide information on how to get there?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If a [Discern Location](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/discern-location) or [Wish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish) spell is used to determine the location of an object or person, is the caster also able to determine how to get there?

For example, if there is a powerful artifact that has been placed in a deep underground city, which is surrounded by a tunnel that is very maze like.

Would the spell simply provide the caster with the city's name?

Would the spell let the caster know the city's name, the fact that it is an underground city, and give a general location?

Would the spell work like a bread crumb trail that lets the caster now find the place despite the large maze outside it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Discern Location only says it tells you where the target is. It does no more than that. Wish, if used to duplicate Discern Location, does the same thing.

That said, Wish can also duplicate [Find The Path](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/find-the-path), which *does* tell you how to get somewhere, including how to get through a maze like set of tunnels.

Wish also has the ability to teleport written into it, so it could just take you to the location after you find it (either with Discern Location or with another Wish).

Answer (score 5):

Spells don't do more than they say they do.

Discern Location says clearly that it provides the name and nothing more. Wish used this way counts as a duplicate of Discern Location, so it does no more or less than Discern Location.